# Как не переводить в строку json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, строки, словари

`jsonStr = json.loads(mydict, ensure_ascii=False,)`

Есть такой код, `jsonStr` - строка, можно сделать так, чтобы это был словарь?
Как сохранить `Json` и перевести его в `Dict`

Comment: если в mydict привычный джейсон (ключ - значение), то jsonStr и есть словарь, а никакая не строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: Учитывая уточнение вопроса ответ будет следующим:
Чтобы сохранить данные в виде json'а нужно его сериализовать.

```
import json

fn = 'my_data.json'
with open(fn, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  json.dump(mydict, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Чтобы его десериализовать - считать обратно и пользоваться данными нужно следующее:

```
import json

fn = 'my_data.json'
with open(fn, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  mydict = json.load(f)
```

Comment: смотрите, при выключении кода, mydict - сбрасывается, поэтому я хочу использовать json

Comment: но как вы сказали - json строка, поэтому я не знаю то делать

Comment: Тогда вопрос нужно правильно формулировать. Как сохранить в json и потом снова его прочитать, вернув dict. В таком случае всё просто. (Дополните вопрос, чтобы мой ответ был в тему)